# How to set columns from a joined entity in JPAQuery and Querydsl

Tags: java, jpa, querydsl

I am in the process of internationalizing an existing software using. As part of it I have a table which, reduced to the simplest case, is:

```
ID AUTONUMERIC
ID_OF_TEXT NUMBER
TEXT VARCHAR
```

The text column must be translated to new languages (which may or may not be present). So there is another new table with colunmns:

```
ID_OF_TEXT NUMBER
LANGUAGE_CODE VARCHAR
TRANSLATED_TEXT VARCHAR
```

There is already an entity to represent the base table and this entity cannot be changed. It's generated code looks like:

```
class QMyBaseEntity extends EntityPathBase<MyBaseEntity> {
    NumberPath<Long> id = createNumber("id", Long.class);
    NumberPath<Long> toTranslateId = createNumber("toTranslateId", Long.class);
    StringPath text = createString("text");
}
```

and the generated code for the translations look up table looks like:

```
@Generated("com.mysema.query.codegen.EntitySerializer")
class QTranslationLookup extends EntityPathBase<TranslationLookup> {
    NumberPath<Long> id = createNumber("id", Long.class);
    NumberPath<Long> translationId = createNumber("translationId", Long.class);
    StringPath languageCode = createString("languageCode");
    StringPath translated_text = createString("translated_text");
}
```

I want the field `text` of `MyBaseEntity` to take the value of the translation table (if it exists) instead of its original one. There is already a very complex query that I cannot change except for adding a join like:

```
String languageCode = "de";
JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
query.from(qMyBaseEntity);
// add lots of other joins and stuff here
query.leftJoin(qTranslationLookup)
        .on(qTranslationLookup.translationId.eq(qMyBaseEntity.toTranslateId)
        .and(qTranslationLookup.languageCode.eq(languageCode)));
List<MyBaseEntity> results = query.list(qMyBaseEntity);
```

With the minimum change possible to the existing code, how do I set the value of the translation in the `results` list so that the returned entity instances contain the translation in the `text` column instead of the original value from the old (untranslated) table?

Answer (score 1):

*Mysema isn't a framework, QueryDSL is. QueryDSL used to be developed by Mysema, but isn't anymore and the package has since moved to the `com.querydsl` group id.*

You can't override the values of managed properties in an entity projection. The values will always be the actual field values from the entity. Entities cannot be used as DTO's. If you want to project different kinds of expressions, you need to use tuple projection.

```
List<Tuple> results = query.from(qMyBaseEntity)
    .leftJoin(qTranslationLookup)
    .on(qTranslationLookup.translationId.eq(qMyBaseEntity.toTranslateId)
    .and(qTranslationLookup.languageCode.eq(languageCode)))
    .select(qMyBaseEntity, qTranslationLookup.translatedText.coalesce(qMyBaseEntity.text))
    .fetch()
```

Alternatively, you could for example return a mapping:

```
Map<MyBaseEntity, String> results = query.from(qMyBaseEntity)
    .leftJoin(qTranslationLookup)
    .on(qTranslationLookup.translationId.eq(qMyBaseEntity.toTranslateId)
    .and(qTranslationLookup.languageCode.eq(languageCode)))
    .transform(GroupBy.groupBy(qMyBaseEntity).as(
         qTranslationLookup.translatedText.coalesce(qMyBaseEntity.text))
    .fetch()
```

Or you could use QueryDSL's DTO projection:

```
List<ResultDTO> results = query.from(qMyBaseEntity)
    .leftJoin(qTranslationLookup)
    .on(qTranslationLookup.translationId.eq(qMyBaseEntity.toTranslateId)
    .and(qTranslationLookup.languageCode.eq(languageCode)))
    .select(Projections.constructor(ResultDTO.class, qMyBaseEntity, qTranslationLookup.translatedText.coalesce(qMyBaseEntity.text))
    .fetch()
```